# 2nd element in array (int array) isn't being processed in outside function for some reason

Tags: arrays, c, function, element

I'm new to programming and started learning structs. I am making a program that asks for a student name, 3 test results, and then those results get passed through a function that gets rid of the lowest mark.

When I pass it through this function for some reason it just doesn't show the 2nd element and replaces it with the 3rd element while the 3rd element is replaced with a 0.

I've altered my code to show what I mean. If you could be so kind as to copy and paste to see what I mean. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 1
#define TESTS 3

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int test[TESTS];
    float avg;
}Results;

void best(Results *marks[TESTS]);

int main()
{
    Results nameArr[SIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name for student %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%\s", nameArr[i].name);
        printf("Enter marks (Out of 100) for %s:\n", nameArr[i].name);
        for(int j=0; j<TESTS; j++)
        {
            printf("Test %d: ", j+1);
            scanf("%d", &nameArr[i].test[j]);
        }
    }printf("\n");

    for(int i= 0; i<TESTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Test %d in main() = %d\n", i+1, nameArr[0].test[i]);
    }printf("\n");

    for(int i= 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        best(&nameArr[i].test);
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void best(Results *marks[TESTS])
{
    for(int i= 0; i<TESTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Test %d in function = %d\n", i+1, marks[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("Test %d in function = %d\n", i+1, marks[i]);` invokes *undefined behavior* because `Results*` is passed where `int` is expected, to print pointers, you should use `%p` specifyer and cast the pointer to print to `void*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `nameArr[i].test` is `int[TESTS]`, not `Results*[TESTS]`. Use correct type for the function argument.

Also arrays in expression are automatically converted to pointers (some exceptions exist), so you don't need `&` before arrays (at least in this case).

Some other points:

- You should add `#include <stdio.h>` to use `printf()` and `scanf()`.
- `\s` is an invalid escape sequence. You should use `"%s"` instead of `"%\s"`.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* add this */
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 1
#define TESTS 3

typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int test[TESTS];
    float avg;
}Results;

/* fix argument type */
void best(int marks[TESTS]);
/* void best(Results *marks[TESTS]); */

int main()
{
    Results nameArr[SIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name for student %d: ", i+1);
        /* remove invalid escape sequence */
        scanf("%s", nameArr[i].name);
        /* scanf("%\s", nameArr[i].name); */
        printf("Enter marks (Out of 100) for %s:\n", nameArr[i].name);
        for(int j=0; j<TESTS; j++)
        {
            printf("Test %d: ", j+1);
            scanf("%d", &nameArr[i].test[j]);
        }
    }printf("\n");

    for(int i= 0; i<TESTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Test %d in main() = %d\n", i+1, nameArr[0].test[i]);
    }printf("\n");

    for(int i= 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        /* remove & */
        best(nameArr[i].test);
        /* best(&nameArr[i].test); */
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


/* fix argument type */
void best(int marks[TESTS])
/* void best(Results *marks[TESTS]) */
{
    for(int i= 0; i<TESTS; i++)
    {
        printf("Test %d in function = %d\n", i+1, marks[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As MikeCAT pointed out in the comments, you are invoking undefined behavior with your printf() statements. Argument of type "%d" expects a decimal value but you are giving it a pointer to a struct which would expect an argument of "%p". I would recommend you research the printf() function here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

This will help you get a better understanding of how to use it to accurately and appropriately print the values you would like to see.